# how to get the value of "id" of the last record in a mysql data base through php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

let's say there is a database called "db" and a table called "tb" and with some records in it. first column is "ID" which is "auto increment". i want to get the last record's ID to a php page.(i have already created the connection to the db)

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tb` or `SELECT ID FROM tb ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` or ...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id from tb ORDER BY id desc limit 1
```

Comment: `DESC` not `ASC` as OP stated `i want to get the last record's ID`

Comment: Updated check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `table` ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$rs = mysqli_query("SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM tb");
$res = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
echo $id = $res->max_id;
?>
```